# Upload video on Metacafe through web-application

Tags: video, upload, youtube

Can we upload video on Metacafe from our web application ? Is there any API/webservice provede by Metacafe ?
I know Youtube, Dailymotion etc.. provides such features, but not getting anything for Metacafe.

Please let me know if anyone has idea.

Thanks.